# Google sheets, hide/remove data validation dropdown..unless another cell is not empty?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a column that has dropdown list with data validation, and its applied infinitely down that column. So I have lots of cells with the little dropdown arrow which is annoying.

Is there a way to remove that dropdown arrow....IF say "Date" or "Name" column is empty?
I want the drop to to show only when I have started inputting data to that row, I will never start with the drop down, I start with date. So ideally, as soon after entering the date, the dropdown arrow appears.

Can that be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the dropdown arrows by unchecking **Show Dropdown List in Cell** on Data Validation dialog:

[image]

This will show the dropdown list only when you start entering data to the cell.

[image]

Comment: Kindly let me know in the comments if this solved your issue or there are problems. Thank you.

Comment: yes this solved my question, thanks